# image of $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-3| < 3\}$ under the mapping , $w =T(z) $ is choose the coorect statement

Tags: complex-analysis

let $T : \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}  \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ be the  bilinear transformation such that  $T(6) =0$, $T(3-3i) = i$ and $T(0) = \infty $. then  image of $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-3| < 3\}$  under the mapping , $w =T(z) $ is

choose the coorect  statement

$a)$ $\{ w \in \mathbb{C} : Im(w)  < 0 \}$

$b)$ $\{ w \in \mathbb{C} : Re(w) < 0 \}$

$c)$$\{ w \in \mathbb{C} : I
m(w) > 0\}$

$d)$$\{ w \in \mathbb{C} : Re(w) > 0\}$

## My attempt:

$\frac {(w-w_1)(w_2  -w_3)}{(w_1- w_2)(w_3-  w)}= \frac{(z-z_1)(z_2  -z_3)}{(z_1- z_2)(z_3-  z)}$

$z_1 = 6$, $z_2 = (3 - 3i)$ and $z_3 = 0$

and $w_1 = 0 , w_2 =i , w_3 = \infty$

$\frac {(w-0)(i  -\infty)}{(0- i)(\infty -  w)}=\frac{(z-6)(3  -3i)}{(6-3+3i )(0-  z)}$

after  that i don't  know how to proceed further ..

any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks   u

Comment: Do you reall mean "bilinear"?

Comment: yes,, @amsmath...

Comment: $3-3i$ is on the boundary of $D$. So $T(3-3i) = i$ must be on the boundary of $T(D)$. Hence, (a) and (c) must be false.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you mean is "fractional linear" and not "bilinear". A bilinear map maps from $X\times Y$ to $Z$, where $X,Y,Z$ are vector spaces.

Comment: @amsmath..this  exam question  that given like that  i have check again one more

Comment: You have $T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Use the given information to obtain $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: actually  im not getting ur point   ,,see my given answer...can  u colloborate that  with  ur given hints T(z)

Comment: No. I don't understand what you are doing there because you don't define your symbols (which is not the first time).

Comment: Imagine that you are walking through the boundary of the open circle of radius $3$, then On which side is your left hand? _answer:_ left. Hence the image of the interior will be on the left side aswell. So in your particular case the answer is $b)$